# How to create a broadcast receiver to launch activity with FCM

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

So am actually making a video calling app so when we receive a message from FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) Theres an activity which should be launched basically notifying user that theres an incoming call.
So I have added these in the activity which launches

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

And this is the code in Firebase Messaging service to launch activity inside onMessageRecieved

```
private void sendIncomingCall(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String imageUrl = remoteMessage.getData().get("imageurl");
        String username = remoteMessage.getData().get("username");

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),IncomingCallActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("user", user);
        intent.putExtra("imageUrl", imageUrl);
        intent.putExtra("username", username);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startactivity(intent);

    }
```

Now I saw that making a broadcast receiver would help but I dont have idea about it. It would  be helpful if someone can tell how to create a broadcast receiver for this scenario I dont care about app being foreground or background or even locked the activity should launch in all these cases.
If those information are not enough I am willing to share more information